# Multi-Threaded Java Server

Tags: java, networking, socket

As practice I wanted to write a Socket in Java:

```
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 21/02/15 Time: 13:30 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

public class MyServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);

        while (true) {
            new Thread(new ServerSocketThread(serverSocket.accept())).start();
        }
    }

}
```

and the rest of it:

```
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 21/02/15 Time: 18:14 */

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ServerSocketThread implements Runnable {

    Socket socket;

    public ServerSocketThread(Socket accept) {
        this.socket = accept;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            Scanner s = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            String readLine;

            while (!(readLine = s.nextLine()).equals("bye")) {
                System.out.println(readLine);
            }

            new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream()).write("Bye then..");
            socket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I wanted to write it as clean as possible. Any improvements, suggestions?

I can use it like this:

> ```
> Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$ telnet localhost 8888
> Trying ::1...
> Connected to localhost.
> Escape character is '^]'.
> koray
> tugay
> asdfako
> bye
> Connection closed by foreign host.
> ```

Comment: Your title should only state what your code does, and not what concerns you have. Also, please give a brief explanation in what your code exactly does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a lot to say about such a simple program, mainly nitpicks:

- Member fields that you don't need to expose to the outside should be `private`, such as the `socket` in `ServerSocketThread`.
- Whenever you can, make member fields `final`, for example the `socket` in `ServerSocketThread`.
- The `Socket` parameter in the constructor of `ServerSocketThread` is poorly named `accept`. It would be better to call it what it is: `socket`
- `s` for a `Scanner` is not a great name either. How about `scanner` ?
- It's a bit odd that the server doesn't talk back to the client, just prints stuff on its console.
- If the program gets more complex later:

  - It might be good to move the literal string like "bye" to a constant variable, as it's somewhat special, being the special terminating sequence
  - Printing stack trace on the console is considered bad practice
  - Printing pretty much anything to the console is considered bad practice

  However, at this point, your program being a toy, it doesn't really matter, just for the record...

Comment: I tried to make it as readable as possible.

Comment: Oh you succeeded, it's definitely nicely readable! (It will still be so after applying my suggestions ;-)